# How aggregate a pandas date timeline series only by hour

Tags: python, pandas, date, datetime, timeline

I have a pandas timeline table containing dates objects and scores:

```
          datetime   score
2018-11-23 08:33:02      4
2018-11-24 09:43:30      2
2018-11-25 08:21:34      5
2018-11-26 19:33:01      4
2018-11-23 08:50:40      1
2018-11-23 09:03:10      3
```

I want to aggregate the score by hour without taking into consideration the date, the result desired is :

```
08:00:00        10
09:00:00        5
19:00:00        4
```

So basically I have to remove the date-month-year, and then group score by hour,

I tried this command

```
monthagg = df['score'].resample('H').sum().to_frame()
```

Which does work but takes into consideration the date-month-year, How to remove DD-MM-YYYY and aggregate by Hour?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One possible solution is use [`DatetimeIndex.floor`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DatetimeIndex.floor.html) for set minutes and seconds to `0` and then convert `DatetimeIndex` to strings by [`DatetimeIndex.strftime`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DatetimeIndex.strftime.html), then aggregate `sum`:

```
a = df['score'].groupby(df.index.floor('H').strftime('%H:%M:%S')).sum()
#if column datetime
#a = df['score'].groupby(df['datetime'].dt.floor('H').dt.strftime('%H:%M:%S')).sum()
print (a)
08:00:00    10
09:00:00     5
19:00:00     4
Name: score, dtype: int64
```

Or use [`DatetimeIndex.hour`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DatetimeIndex.hour.html) and aggregate `sum`:

```
a = df.groupby(df.index.hour)['score'].sum()
#if column datetime
#a = df.groupby(df['datetime'].dt.hour)['score'].sum()
print (a)
datetime
8     10
9      5
19     4
Name: score, dtype: int64
```

Answer (score 2):

Setup to generate a frame with datetime objects:

```
import datetime
import pandas as pd

rows = [datetime.datetime.now() + datetime.timedelta(hours=i) for i in range(100)]
df = pd.DataFrame(rows,columns = ["date"])
```

You can now add a hour-column like this, and then group by it:

```
df["hour"] = df["date"].dt.hour
df.groupby("hour").sum()
```

Answer (score 1):

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'datetime':['2018-11-23 08:33:02 ','2018-11-24 09:43:30',
                               '2018-11-25 08:21:34',
                               '2018-11-26 19:33:01','2018-11-23 08:50:40',
                               '2018-11-23 09:03:10'],'score':[4,2,5,4,1,3]})
df['datetime']=pd.to_datetime(df['datetime'], errors='coerce')
df["hour"] = df["datetime"].dt.hour
df.groupby("hour").sum()
```

**Output:**

```
8   10
9   5
19  4
```